# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how to check the style tag of a particular element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have this

```
Then /^the "([^\"]*)" tag with the id "([^\"]*)" should have the style "([^\"]*)"$/ do |tag,id,style|
  if page.respond_to? :should
      page.should have_selector(tag, :id => id, :style => style)
    else
      assert page.has_selector?(tag, :id => id, :style => style)
    end
end
```

And This is my cuke step

```
    And the "div" tag with the id "preview" should have the style "display: block;"
```

And this is the error I get:

```
undefined method `has_selector?' for #<Capybara::Session:0x1065b5fc0> (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use something similar to 
  page.should have_xpath("//tag[@class='class', @id='id']")

```
Then /^I should see trivial div$/ do 
  page.has_xpath?("//div[@style='display:none' and @id='my_form']") 
end
```

this one definitely works

Comment: got this error NativeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve XPath >//div[@style='display: none;', @id='preview']< on HtmlPage(http://cucumber.test.com/objects/dance-dance-dance/build)@1286076580 (Culerity::CulerityException)